# Android Google Plus SDK: how to get callback on the +1 button (PlusOneButton)

Tags: android, api, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

I added a +1 button in my Android app. I would like to add a callback in order to know what happened after the user clicked on the +1 button (did he validate its +1 ?, did he abort ? ...)

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to check when the button is clicked and later check the result of the activity.

```
static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST = 1;
...
mPlusOneButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {

        //here you can handle the initial click

        //Start the activity to display the +1 confirmation dialog.
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST);
    }
});
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PLUS_ONE_REQUEST) {
        switch(resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                //here the operation was successful
                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                //here the user backed out or failed
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sources:
[Handling the click](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener.html)
[Getting a result from an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

I hope that this is what your were asking, and more importantly that this was helpful.

Comment: What do you call the "activity to display the +1 confirmation dialog" ? What does this confirmation dialog look like ? Is it the dialog with  the sign in / sign out / revoke buttons ? Or the Google Plus dialog to post something on the user G+ wall ? Thanks.

Comment: This confirmation dialog verifies that the user is signed in. The +1 button does not display a confirmation alert because it can be undone by reclicking the button.